# GetResponse 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to send a POST method to `https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts` from my Vue using axios. I'm unsure why I kept getting a 400 Bad Request. I've tried checking the Network tab on Mozilla dev tools but there doesn't seem to have any Response message it just returned me.

> XHR OPTIONS https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 763ms]

I have double confirm from GetResponse documentation to add the Content-Type header to `application/json` and to set my API key as `X-Auth-Token: api-key <API_KEY>`.

**NOTE**: I am also getting `CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing` but I believe it does not have anything to do with the Error 400.

Here are some code snippets from my Vue file.

**axios-config.js**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_GET_RESPONSE_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Auth-Token': `api-key ${process.env.VUE_APP_GET_RESPONSE_API_KEY}`,
  }
});
```

**Vue**

```
import axios from "@/services/axios-config.js";

user: {
  name: "",
  campaign: {
    campaignId: `${process.env.VUE_APP_GET_RESPONSE_CAMPAIGN_ID}`
  },
  email: "",
  customFieldValue: {
    customFieldId: "interest",
    value: []
  }
}

async callSubscribeAPI() {  
  try{
    const response = await axios.post("/contacts",this.user);

    console.log(response);
  }catch(error){
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
(async() => {

  const url = 'https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts';

  const payload = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url,
    headers: {
      "X-Auth-Token": "api-key 12345*****",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }    
  });

  console.log("payload", payload.data);

})()
```